# What types of circuits are used in neuromorphic circuit design?

Tags: circuit-design

What types of circuits are commonly used in neuromorphic circuit design? My background is in AI and neuroscience, and I would like to refresh my knowledge of circuits before taking a neuromorphic engineering course.

Comment: Those will be CMOS analog circuits implemented on ASICs. For implementations on breadboard you’d be using cmos transistor array packages or even bipolar transistors since many basic building blocks of those circuits can be built equivalently with BJTs. As for the background needed: enough circuit theory to grasp CMOS circuits, plus a basic analog CMOS IC design course would be handy for tool familiarity. Doesn’t the course list prerequisites? I can’t imagine it would be offered to students without EE background…

Comment: For circuits look into any of the “neural analog computing” papers. You’ll need grasp of basic CMOS analog building blocks like current sources, differential amplifiers, current conveyors – at least. Most papers go into sufficient detail to figure out what building blocks you need to Google to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, that's already very helpful! As far as I undertand, the class is not supposed to be in depth. It's available for students of AI, CS, and nanotechnology. Given the varied bakckground of these people, we will first be introduced to the basic conceps I imagine, but there is plenty of time in a two month course module to go further.

Comment: I have no idea how one would teach it to people without basic undergraduate EE knowledge. I'm not sure how much EE do the AI, CS and nanotech folk can be presumed to know. It's really hard to do anything practical when talking about *circuits* without having the background in basic circuit analysis and active devices used in such circuits (those are all active circuits). Perhaps you could toss in relevant snippets of the course curriculum? If not posted yet, ask the professor for it. I'm quite curious. Ask how many times has this course been taught, and with what results.

Comment: The listed majors hopefully come with enough calculus to grasp some of the circuit analysis introduced on the fly, but I can't imagine teaching the basics of MOS circuits in parallel with teaching applications in neuromorphic circuits - all in two months. I expect nothing good to come out of it, unless the title of the course is highly misleading. Do all possible due diligence to learn exactly what the course covers, how much experience is had in teaching it - both in the department and by the particular teacher, what textbook or references are used, etc. Share by editing the question! :)

Comment: Now, if the "circuit design" means not what is implied in EE courses, then perhaps they are using analog computers, which would be pretty cool and much more practical than teaching MOS on-the-fly, since analog computers pretty much implement calculus operators directly. Short of them having a lab full of [The Analog Thing](https://the-analog-thing.org/) or an equivalent, it'd all be based on simulations - cool, but the fun factor is disputable. Hard to beat emulating a neuron firing using real electronic circuits, even if they are just analog computer blocks.